# detect words with the same root

Tags: java, regex, nlp, similarity, linguistics

I am currently developing an automated **Index-Generator** for pdf-files in Java. The concept is pretty simple (right now): I iterate over every word in the pdf, compare with an ignore list (something like the 10000 most common words in that language) and then add it to a `com.google.common.collect.HashMultimap` with the word as String and a HashSet of pages, the word occurs on.

This is working pretty fine, but still I am getting words in all different **declination/conjugation** forms as separate items in the index. I was thinking of just comparing a relative sub-string of those words, but for instance in the German language (which the program is intended for) with all its irregularities, there is very less benefit of this approach.

Any other ideas, libraries, regex's, whatsoever?
Thanks in advance

Comment: [opennlp.tools.stemmer.snowball](http://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/apidocs/opennlp-tools/opennlp/tools/stemmer/snowball/SnowballStemmer.ALGORITHM.html)

Comment: Lucene, in different variations: [`org.tartarus.snowball.ext.German2Stemmer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/analyzers-common/org/tartarus/snowball/ext/German2Stemmer.html) and [`org.apache.lucene.analysis.de.GermanLightStemmer`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de/GermanLightStemmer.html). The [default analyzer](https://lucene.apache.org/core/5_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/de/GermanAnalyzer.html) uses the light stemmer followed by germanized snowball.

Comment: For NLP tasks, you should search for an NLP library, which contains data and rules of the language. Asking people to build a regex for this is like asking people to reinvent the wheel and do the research for you.

Comment: I wasn't asking for a regex or any pre-built solution, just for a hint to get in the right direction. Maybe that was unclear in my question, sorry for that. But thanks to the other replies, I will check them out tonight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process of reducing words to their common root is called lemmatization. A lemmatizer will map words like `eaten`, `eats` and `ate` to `eat`.

I'm not experienced with German but different libraries to perform this task are available for English, for example [Stanford CoreNLP](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), which is a full-fledged NLP library providing many other features as well. It may support German as well, but I'm not sure.

Otherwise, a Google search for "German lemmatizer" will provide enough results, I think.

You can also user a stemmer, which is a simpler version of lemmatization. A stemmer is usually a rule-based component and is able to reduce words to their common root, but the output word will not always be valid: for example the word `engine` might be stemmed as `engin`. If you require that the words are still valid after this operation, lemmatization will be a better solution, otherwise stemming might be better because it is way faster to execute.

Comment: I played around with Stanford CoreNLP and at least for english texts it works alright

Answer (score 0):

You can get inflection data for German from http://danielnaber.de/morphologie/. This is also what e.g. LanguageTool uses internally for [its analysis](https://github.com/languagetool-org/languagetool/blob/master/languagetool-language-modules/de/src/main/java/org/languagetool/tagging/de/GermanTagger.java). (disclosure: linking my own projects here)